How to change a pydantic list of objects into list of strings?
I'm using SQLModel for an API.
I want the object to be like this:
class Post(SQLModel):
    id: int
    categories: list[str]  # category.name

instead of nested objects:
class Post(SQLModel):
    id: int
    categories: list[Category]

Do I have to change the serialization function or is there a way to do this automatically?

As far as I understood Post is your db model. I would highly recommend to separate you db model (should reflect the database structure) from dto (should be used for comfortable data transfer between application components)
class PostDTO(pydantic.BaseModel):
    id: int
    categories: list[str]

    @classmethod
    def from_db_model(cls, model: Post) -> "PostDTO":
        """Build Post DTO based on db model."""

        return cls(
            id=model.id,
            categories=[category.name for category in model.categories]
        )
   
post = Post(...)
post_dto = PostDTO.from_db_model(model=post)


Don't be afraid to create an extra object if it makes your code more scalable, readable and logical!

There is not an automatic way to extract a property from an incoming object to be validated.  You would need to use a field_validator to do this "automatically":
class Post(SQLModel):
    id: int
    categories: list[str]

    @field_validator("categories")
    @classmethod
    def normalize_categories(cls, value, info):
        return [item.name for item in value]

